# force component to re-render

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
 
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ todos: [] });
 
  useEffect(async () => {
    const result = await axios(
      'https://myapi.com/todos',
    );
 
    setData(result.data);
  });
 
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.todos.map(todo => (
        <li key={todo.id}>
          {todo.title}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
 
export default App;
```

I have components (like above) that fetch data e.g. todos within the useEffect hook. I also have a web socket that informs me when e.g. a todo has an update. In this case, i want the component to be re-rendered to get the new data.

How do you do that?

I've read about tools like [useSWR](https://swr.vercel.app/) that pulls in new data after a timeout. But that's not the optimal solution because I know when there will be an update.

This would not be a problem with redux, as I could simply fetch the new data via action. But I don't want to have everything in the redux state because it isn't actually necessary

Comment: The component should re-render when you update the state using `setData`, is that not happening?

Comment: Do a [forceUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate)

Comment: @DBS The question is how do I get the re-render from the websocket to trigger

Comment: **WebSocket.onmessage** is an eventListener for Websockets. call the component to update from there. read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)

Comment: @Eldshe That's clear. But how do i get access the component? Is this something like i subscribe to the socket inside the useEffect hook?

Comment: That question has also been asked already ;)    [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941364/update-react-component-without-parent-outside-of-it)

Comment: @Eldshe thanks! I think I have an idea now

Comment: also [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46056865/how-to-re-render-table-component-upon-receiving-a-notification-from-web-socket-i) lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do below, you need to bring WebSocket connection inside to your component if you don't want to use Redux

```
export default function App() {
        const [data, setData] = useState({ todos: [] });
        const [isStopped, setStopped] = useState(false);
        const ws = useRef(null);
       
      useEffect(async () => {
          const result = await axios(
          'https://myapi.com/todos',
          );
         setData(result.data);
       });
        useEffect(() => {
            ws.current = new WebSocket("wss://your urls/");
            ws.current.onopen = () => console.log("ws opened");
            ws.current.onclose = () => console.log("ws closed");
    
            return () => {
                ws.current.close();
            };
        }, []);
    
        useEffect(() => {
            if (!ws.current) return;
    
            ws.current.onmessage = e => {
                if (isStopped) return;
                const message = JSON.parse(e.data);
               setData(e.data);
                console.log("e", message);
            };
        }, [isStopped]);
    
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => setPause(!isStopped)}>
                    {isStopped ? "Resume" : "Stop"}
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
```